# JQuery select specific element in ul

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  open = false;
  sort = false;
});

// On Category click
$(".category-name").click(function() {
  if (open == false && sort == false) {
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-down").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-up").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
    open = true;
  } else {
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-down").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-up").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).next().slideUp("fast");
    open = false;
  }
});

// Sortable on button click
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function() {
  if (sort == false) {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({ 
      revert: true, 
      axis: 'y',
      cursor: "move",    
    });
    $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable("enable");
    $(".fa-cog").addClass("rotating");
    sort = true;
  } else {
    $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable("disable");
    $(".fa-cog").removeClass("rotating");
    sort = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://5.9.177.134/animation-ui/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

#animation-menu {
    margin: 2rem;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#navbar {
    width: 25rem;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
}

#scrollable {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}


/* SCROLLBAR */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.9);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #888;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

#back2Top {
    z-index: 50;
    left: 24rem;
    bottom: 9rem;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(50, 48, 49);
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 2rem;
}

.d-flex {
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: default;
}

.category-name {
    background-color: #0088ad;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black;
    user-select: none;
}

.category-animation {
    display: none;
    background-color: #00ad65;
    justify-content: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.category-name>.fa-caret-up {
    display: none;
}

.fa-caret-down,
.fa-caret-up {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.star {
    color: #ebdb34 !important;
    padding-top: 0.44rem;
    padding-right: 6.5rem;
    position: absolute;   
}

.star2 {
    color: #ebdb34 !important;
    padding-top: 0.44rem;
    padding-left: 8rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.category-name:hover,
.category-animation:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

a,
a:hover {
    color: #212529;
}

.category-dropdown {
    display: none;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="./css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="animation-menu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark elegant-color" id="navbar">
                <span class="navbar-brand ml-2">Animationen</span>
                <button class="navbar-toggler">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog mr-2"></i>
                </button> 
            </nav>
       
            <div id="scrollable">
                <a id="back2Top" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i></a>
                <div class="search-bar ml-3 mr-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                        <label for="form1">Animation suchen</label>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="sortable">
                    <li class="category">
                        <a class="category-name d-flex"><i class="fa fa-star star"></i> Favoriten <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up ml-2"></i></a>
                        <ul class="category-dropdown">
                            <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1 <i class="far fa-star star2"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1 <i class="far fa-star star2"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="category">
                        <a class="category-name d-flex">Tanzen <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up ml-2"></i></a>
                        <ul class="category-dropdown">
                            <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1 <i class="far fa-star star2"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1 <i class="far fa-star star2"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/backToTop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi, guys.
I got a problem with JQuery.
I still haven't understood how to select certain things so that the variability remains.

I'm hoping you guys can help me with my problem.

I would like to select the class `.star2` as soon as you click on `.category-name`.

When clicking `.category-name`, both `.star2` should *fade out/fade in*.
And I just don't know how to select `.star2` correctly.

Comment: `$('.category-name').click(event => { const $cat = $(event.target); const $stars = $cat.find('.star'); // manipulate $stars});`

Comment: Please see [mcve] - with the emphasis on *minimal*

Comment: `$(".star2", this).toggleFade()` (in side click event handler without `=>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```js
$(".category-name").click(function() {
  let element = $(this).find('.star');
  element.fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Also, as there are multiple category-name and multiple .star[2] - this will fadeIn/Out based on the last clicked, not the current one

Comment: @freedomn-m you're absolutely correct. I really apologize, for the mistake I made. I have updated the code. And `fadeToggle()` is the best way to do that.